# Uploading Multiple Images With An Input File Field

Tags: php, file-upload

I'm building a simple website where I want to upload images into a folder so I'm doing this by enabling `multiple` in the input box.

Here is my HTML:

```
<input type="file" name="gallery[]" multiple />
```

And here is the PHP:

```
$id = time();
$year = date("Y");
$photo_path = "photos/$year/";
$zip_path = "sets/$year/";

$photo = $_FILES["photo"]["name"];
$gallery = $_FILES["gallery"]["name"];

move_uploaded_file($_FILES["photo"]["tmp_name"],"$photo_path" . $id . ".jpg"); // This Adds Photo To $photo_path
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["gallery"]["tmp_name"],"$zip_path"); // This Doesn't Add 5 Files To $zip_path
```

This adds the photo into the `$photo_path` folder, but doesn't add the selected 5 images to the `$zip_path` folder.

Any ideas where I'm going wrong?

Update:

```
foreach ($_FILES["gallery"] as $file) {

    move_uploaded_file($_FILES["gallery"]["tmp_name"],"$zip_path");

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to handle multiple files in a loop. Here is an example directly from the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php).

```
$uploads_dir = '/uploads';
foreach ($_FILES["pictures"]["error"] as $key => $error) {
    if ($error == UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
        $tmp_name = $_FILES["pictures"]["tmp_name"][$key];
        $name = $_FILES["pictures"]["name"][$key];
        move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, "$uploads_dir/$name");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you calling multiple file upload, it will return an array of files. you can iterate it like:

```
if(count($_FILES['gallery'])) {
    foreach ($_FILES['gallery'] as $key=>$file) {

        //do your upload stuff here
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES['gallery']["tmp_name"][$key], $zip_path . time() . ".jpg");

    }
}
```

Comment: That looks to make sense but It's not uploading any of the images. I've added my code to the end of the original question.